# Problem with mathematical expression

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, decimal

While using exponential operator in C#, the compiler was reporting "**Operator ^ cannot be applied to operands of type int and double.**" While the same was compiling without any errors in VB.NET.

```
//C# Code, error while compiling
decimal i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1) ^ 0.5;

'VB.NET Code. Compiled without errors 
Dim i as decimal = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1) ^ 0.5 'outputs 108.066017177982 as expected
```

To circumvent the C# error, I updated the code to use Math.Pow() which was giving wrong output

```
decimal i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1);
i = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)i, 0.5);
Console.WriteLine(i); //Outputs 12.328828005938 instead of 108.0660172

//Next i changed the datatype to double, still same results
double i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1);
i = Math.Pow(i, 0.5);
Console.WriteLine(i); //Outputs 12.328828005938 instead of 108.0660172
```

While executing the same formula in Excel, gives 108.0660172 as expected.
=1 * (1 +1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1) ^ 0.5

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Is `option strict` on or off in VB?

Comment: There's no "power" operator in C#. `^` is exclusive OR.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I know that there's no exponent operator in C# itself. But heard that you could use Math.Pow instead. The problem is that the result returned by Math.Pow is wrong.

Comment: @AbrahamJP: Your question makes it *sound* like you believe there's an exponent operator: "While using the exponential operator in C#". As Topi pointed out, the result returned by Math.Pow is fine - it's the input which is wrong.

Comment: In your calculations ^ operator is applied only to (1 + 1), while with Math.Pow it is applied to whole expression

Comment: @Abraham: If you want to _Test_, don't complicate with `1 + (1*1) ...`. You will find Pow(152, 0.5) == 12.3 is quite correct.

Comment: @username: Can you help me to convert this piece of code to C# 
"Dim i as decimal = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1) ^ 0.5"

Comment: decimal i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1) ^ 0.5;
equals
var i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * Math.Pow((1 + 1), 0.5);

Comment: What do you think is more likely: that Microsoft made an error in Math.Pow *and you're the first person to notice in ten years* or that you've put a parenthesis in the wrong place?  You can't find the bug because your attitude is wrong; the correct attitude is to assume "my code is wrong" and not "the standard library code is wrong".

Comment: @EricLippert: Initially I was thinking from the view point that, there was some bug in Math.Pow(). Now I realize it was my fault, I had taken out that specific statement from the post. Thank you very much for your constructive criticism. In future I will be running test cases before I ever make such statements. A new lesson learnt and +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C# ^ is not a power operator. It's a Xor operator. Here is the documentation about it: [^ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

As for the reason why it evaluates to 12.32 is that 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * (1 + 1) equals to 152 and sqrt(152) is about 12.32.

On the other hand in VB and Excel it is evaluated as 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * sqrt(2) which is 108.06.
In c# you can express it as `double i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * Math.Pow((1 + 1),0.5);`

Answer (score 5):

Power of 0.5 equals square root.

Square root of your i (2 + 150 = 152) in fact is ~12,33.

Pow() returns the correct answer, be sure to use brackets over what you want to power.

Answer (score 4):

Your VB calculation will be procede as follows:

```
(1 * (1 + 1)) + (75 * 1 * ((1 + 1) ^ 0.5));
```

To get the same result in C# you have to write it as:

```
1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * Math.Pow((1 + 1),0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You applied square root to the entire expression.

Try this instead:

```
double lastPart = (1 + 1);
double sqrt = Math.Pow(lastPart, 0.5);
double i = 1 * (1 + 1) + 75 * 1 * sqrt;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```